# grammar of the sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Do these sentences sound grammatically correct? I mean, for example, you were bad person at school, so you will be your whole life this way or something like that.

> Who you were in the same way always you will.
>
> The way you were all your life the way you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither of those are grammatically correct.

I think this is what you want:

> Who you were is who you will always be.

Sounds like a terrible thing to say to someone...

Comment: Gabriel Luci, What about? "The way you were is the way you will be". Or does it sound terrible too?

Comment: That might be ok, but only with some context. On its own, that makes me think "the way I was about what?" It's not clear if you're talking about someone's entire personality, or just about one thing. Also, "will be" is ambiguous. Do you mean from now into the future? Or starting some time in the future?

Comment: Gabriel Luci, I mean from now into the future. What if just put one word in to make it more clearer, like: "The way you were bad is the way will be"... What about this?

Comment: "The way you were bad" does not sound natural. It's still not clear you are talking about their whole personality ("bad with what?"). What's wrong with the sentence I recommended?

Comment: Gabriel Luci, everything is ok, i just want the using of "the way" if it is possible. Or not?

Comment: You could say "The way you were is the way you will always be." Although I still feel it would need context (the way with what?)

Comment: Gabriel Luci, And how to make a sentence with this "bad"?

Comment: Gabriel Luci, thank you so much

Comment: You would to use a different sentence structure. "If you were a bad person, you will always be a bad person". Or speak in general terms, like "A bad person will never change."

Comment: By the way, can use "as" in this sentence? or is it pointless?

Comment: You couldn't put "as" anywhere in that sentence where it would be grammatically correct. But even if you changed the sentence to use "as", it wouldn't sound natural. You could say "like a bad person", but that would change the meaning of the sentence because being *like* a bad person is different than *being* a bad person.

Comment: thank you once again!